# ReSharper: Typescript error Return types are not relatable

Tags: typescript, resharper

I get 
return types are not relatable

> Overload signature is not compatible with function definition: Return
>   types are not relatable

error with ReSharper plugin in this

```
public getCache<T>(key: string): T;
public getCache<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): T;
public getCache<T>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): T
{
    const result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return result ? JSON.parse(result) as T : defaultValue;
}
```

TypeScript code.

I can see why. Generic parameter T in first overload has nothing in common with T in second overload. I could just write

```
public getCache<T1>(key: string): T1;
public getCache<T2>(key: string, defaultValue: T2): T2;
public getCache<T>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): T
{
    const result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return result ? JSON.parse(result) as T : defaultValue;
}
```

Is there solution for this problem?
*My ReSharper version is 2017.3 (15.5.27130.2024)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TypeScript has optional parameters, an overload doesn't make sense in this case. Simply use the last signature, which is the most generic one and cover other cases:

```
public getCache<T>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): T
{
    const result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return result ? JSON.parse(result) as T : defaultValue;
}
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html (Use Optional Parameters)

Comment: Interesting. I can follow guides, but what if I have method with different input parameters. I still need to fix this error.

Comment: Well, then you cannot fix this problem if the generic types are unrelated. You can put the methods in a class and put the generic type on the class so that all be the same, or simply don’t use overloads.